# Appending Array elements to li's using JsonML

Tags: javascript, jsonml

I tried this approach:

Here I extracted the elements array and prepared the li elements:

```
var instructorsUI = [];
for(var i = 1; i < instructors.length; i++){
    instructorsUI.push(['li', {'id' : instructors[i].id, 'class' : 'ui-state-default'},
                            ['span', {'class' : 'ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'}], 
                             instructors[i].name]); 
}
```

Then I inserted instructorsUI in the main UI, which will be appended later to the HTML document using JsonML.toHTMLText(UI);

```
 UI = ['div',{'class': 'col-md-8 tab-pane','id' : 'course-'+course.id},
        ['div', {'class' : 'col-md-4'},
            ['h4', 'Instrucotrs'],
            ['div', {'class' : 'instructors-container'}
                ['ul', {'class' : 'instructors'}, instructorsUI]
            ]
        ]
```

However this gives me syntax error.

I can write the html code myself but I'm wondering why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your JavaScript through http://www.jshint.com.

You're missing a comma at the end of this line:

> `['div', {'class' : 'instructors-container'}`

And you're missing the final closing `]`.